# Fixing my Apache configuration to work with letsencrypt

Tags: ssl, https, apache2, lets-encrypt

I had https on my wordpress site working with a an ip address and self signed certificate fine. I set up the dns for the domain and installed and ran letsencrypt "successfully" but ssl connections to the domain are still trying to reference the original self signed certificate rather than the newly created ones (where are they?) and I'm not sure where to start troubleshooting

Running Apache2 on Debian Buster

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this was the correct way to fix it, but I went into the apache ssl conf file and changed the paths of the temporary certs i'd set up to the new letsencrypt cert file paths and restarted apache, and it worked!